# Oracle Apex: Validation triggers Process

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two input forms:

- Input1
- Input2

If I click a button, a process is triggered which calls a PL/SQL procedure with these two inputs as parameters.

So the procedure should only be called if the two items do have valid inputs.

If I do this with validation or "Value Required", it's working but the process is still running and I want to avoid that. I tried it with JS and $v to compare the input if its empty or not but it was not working.

I'm working in 18.1 and 5.1 so its not a big difference.

Comment: are you defining DA for the button action? or defining a process with  Button Action=Submit page'

Comment: no the button triggers the process.

Comment: @theGrandOracle you didn't answer the question - how does your button trigger the process - via a page submit, via a dynamic action, or via some javascript?

Comment: via server side condition in the process when pressed the button.

Comment: my procedure takes around 2 minutes so i added before the procedure the apex.waitSpinner. But if the items are empty and i press the button the spinner still is triggered. I want to avoid that but you cant do any conditions in javascript for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put validation into PL/SQL procedure and check whether parameters are OK. Something like this (validating whether they aren't NULL; you didn't mention any other *validation*):

```
if :P1_INPUT_1 is not null and
   :P2_INPUT_2 is not null 
then
   your_procedure(:P1_INPUT_1, :P1_INPUT_2);
end;
```

Comment: that was acutally a simple and nice idea thanks for that